# NATURAL FULL OUTER JOIN or USING, if common attribute is NULL

Tags: postgresql, join, null, natural-join

So if table A is:

```
no | username 
1  | admin
2  | chicken
```

And table B is:

```
id | no
a  | 1
b  | 3
c  | 4
```

Then, I do a NATURAL FULL OUTER JOIN as so:

```
SELECT no
FROM A NATURAL FULL OUTER JOIN
     B;
```

Then, what is the result? And is the result the same for all PostgreSQL implementations?

Because does the 'no' come from table A, or table B, it is ambiguous. But, NATURAL joins combine the 'no'. But what if one of the 'no' is ambiguous, i.e. A.no IS NOT NULL, but B.no IS NULL, which of the 'no' does it pick? And what if A.no and B.no are both NULL?

TL;DR: So the question is, WHAT is the value of the no in SELECT **no**: Is it the A.no or B.no, or is it the COLAESCE of them?

```
SELECT no
FROM A NATURAL FULL OUTER JOIN
     B;
```

Answer (score 2):

First, don't use `natural` for joins.  It is a bug waiting to happen.  As you note in your question, `natural` chooses the join keys based on the *names* of columns.  It doesn't take types into account.  It doesn't even take explicitly declared foreign key relationships in to account.

The particularly insidious problem, though, is that someone reading the query does not see the join keys.  That makes is much harder to debug queries or to modify/enhance them.

So, my advice is to use `using` instead.

```
SELECT no
FROM A FULL OUTER JOIN
     B
     USING (no);
```

What does a `full join` return?  It returns *all* rows from both tables, regardless of whether the join matches or not.  Because a `NULL` comparison always fails, `NULL` will not match in the join conditions.

For example, the following query returns 4 rows not 2 containing a `NULL` value:

```
with x as (
      select NULL::int as id union all select NULL as id
     )
select id
from x full join
     x y
     using (id);
```

You would get the same result with a `natural` join, but I simply don't use that construct.

I'm not 100% sure, but I'm pretty sure that all versions of Postgres that support `full join` would work the same way.  This behavior is derived specifically from the ANSI definitions of `join`s and join conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and insightful answer, but the reason I posted this question is for academic reasons. I know NATURAL JOIN is lazy and bad, as it does not adapt well with schema changes.

But, a natural FULL OUTER join, if the join match fails, then that would make one of the 'no' NULL, maybe it is the A.no, but maybe it is the B.no. In that case, what is the value of 'no'? Is it the COALESCE of them, or is it something else? My question really is, what is the value of 'no'?

I.e. the no in SELECT **no** FROM ...

Comment: I also apologise in advance for my poor wording, hopefully it can sort of make sense. ^^"

Comment: @JamesChen . . . If the value is `NULL` in one of the tables, then `NULL` will be returned.

Comment: I just tried it and 'no' returned a non-NULL answer.

I tried SELECT no FROM A NATURAL FULL OUTER JOIN B WHERE B.no IS NULL; and all of the output 'no' is not NULL. I'm curious to know how does PostgreSQL pick which 'no' to output in this ambiguous case.

Comment: It appears Postgres adds an implied `COALESCE(a.no,b.no)` only for **NATURAL FULL OUTER JOIN**. For  normal `FROM a FULL OUTER JOIN B ON a.no = b.no`, you get the `ambiguous column reference` error. (but again: dont use `NATURAL`)

Comment: @wildplasser: the implicit coalesce on the join column(s) is also done when you join through the `using` clause

Comment: @wildplasser Thanks, it seems so but I'm not sure. Is there official proof that PostgreSQL does that? I can't find it in the PostgreSQL documentation?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : I hadn't thought about USING. Don't know if it is dictated by the SQL standard, but It seems makes sense. @ James Chen : I don't know (and actually, I dont care, since I never use these constructs ;-)

Comment: @JamesChen . . . I am missing your point.  In your data, none of the the values of `no` in the tables are `null`.  The `using` clause and the `natural join` both take the value of `no` from the table with the value.  Hence, you can only get a `NULL` value on a join key when the value is `NULL` in one or both of the tables.  In my example, the values are `NULL`, hence `NULL` appears in the output.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Because it is a FULL OUTER JOIN, you can get a NULL.

If you look when b.no = 4, when that full outer joins with a, then a.no = NULL, but b.no = 4. I assume 'no' does an implicit coalesce, so that 'no' is 4 (my question is, if the implicit coalesce actually does take place or not).